# Send My Incoming SMS to My server (upload or ..)

Tags: android

im trying to write an android app that the second a sms arrives to my phone, it uploads it or sends it to my server on internet, i write the getting the new sms number and body part, but now i dont know should it write senderNum and Message into a file and upload it or its possible to send it directly to my internet server, any idea ? plz tell me with samle code. thanks..

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String sindrome = senderNum  + message;

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                    sendSMS("15555215554", sindrome);
                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
        }
    }

    private byte[] getBytes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private OutputStream openFileOutput(String string, int modePrivate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a simple restful webservice with required parameters and deploy it on your server. Take the url and hit it from your mobile and on server write your logic to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idea, you can use a MySQL DB and a PHP file.

The PHP file will care about save sms in the DB, and it could be something like

```
<?php
// You should consider the idea to put everything in POST request and add "key" values to avoid someone to
// send to your server 1000 sms from the web with just a page reload

$from = $_GET['from'];
$body = $_GET['body'];

if (!is_numeric($from))
{
    // Invalid input
    // Do nothing
    exit();
}

// connect to the MYSQL server
$mysqli = new MySQLi(...);

/*
 * DB:
 * PHONE NUMBER | BODY
 * X            | X
 *
 * You can anyway add more info like sending time etc.
 */

// run the query insert
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO sms (number, body) VALUES (?, ?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $from, $body);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
// now you have in your database the sms

// close mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();


?>
```

Then you can use an AsyncTask or an Handler to run the request from the Android application.

Ok, maybe i missed something like close some resource.. but everything should be ok.

```
// As number i think SenderNumber is the number of who send the SMS
// message is here the message is saved
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // OK
        // Here you have senderNum and message

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Since it's  a GET reuqest you can pass params directly
        // but as i said, a POST could be more better
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("YOUR_URL_HERE?number=" + number + "&body=" + message);
        String responseBody;
        HttpResponse response;

        try
        {
            // We run the request
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            // now i need to know if everything is ok
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            // OK!
            if (statusCode == 200)
            {
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                // Now in responseBody you have the response of the request
                // If you don't need it, remove it
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

It should help you to understand how you could do the code.

Comment: thanks for your idea its great.. i would really apreciate if you could  say more about the android side, variables of number and body are senderNum and message in my code, how do i send it to server??!

Comment: i edited the answer, it help you? (sorry for the late, i was busy.. but the code should be OK too.)

Comment: i am trying it its great,  thank u, you are such a nice friend, i'll let you know..